# Java - show Application Name instead of "Java Printing" in the Printing Details Window

Tags: java, printing

In my java printing program, when I print any document using Java, the document prints in the "name of Java Printing" instead of my Application name. How do I show the name of my application in the printing details window of the printer? Any help will be appreciated.

[image: print]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* use [`setJobName(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#setJobName(java.lang.String)) which sets the name of
the document to be printed.

```
printJOB.setJobName("YourPrintName");//You can specify your appName here
```